# What sets the TLS version used in C#

Tags: c#, ssl

I have a C# web application which has references to a large number of projects.

The root web project is set to 4.7.1 framework version

In one of the sub projects, where a web request is made using WebRequest.Create(), that project is also set to 4.7.1

It was my understanding that anything from 4.6 and up uses Tls 1.2, but when I run the project,

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol
```

resolves to Ssl3

This application is hosted in Azure, not sure if that has an impact

So, what setting dictates which TLS to use? This works in our VM with TLS 1.2 the only enabled setting, but not in Azure

Comment: "This application is hosted in Azure" - are you running in an Azure App Service (Azure Website)? If so, note they're all upgraded to .NET 4.7.2 now.

Comment: Yes, app services, so why is TLS resolving to Ssl3?

Comment: With `WebRequest`, that is the default: `SSL3` + `TLS1.0`. `HttpClient` treats it differently, it can select it, if the handshake requires it. Also note that from FW 4.7.2,  `ServicePointManager` is not required anymore to select the `SSL` protocol. It can be set directly using the [HttpClientHandler.SslProtocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.sslprotocols) property (which is just a stub in FW 4.7.1).

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `SecurityProtocol` property during your application's startup or before making any request:

```
const SecurityProtocolType tlsOnly = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = tlsOnly;
```

Comment: Yes, but why isn't the project framework enforcing this?

Comment: @andrewb If the behaviour was changed in a point-release of the .NET Framework it could potentially break many applications and systems depending on this behaviour. Microsoft values backwards-compatibility very heavily and the risk of a POODLE attack and associated damage (and cost to Microsoft) is less than the problems caused by breaking existing applications.